# Ember Multi Select Selection Not Working

Tags: ember.js

Does anyone know why this multi-select isn't showing the two pre-selected values? I expect these two would be preselected: 'Option 0' and 'Option 2'

http://jsfiddle.net/b75w560d/1/

I'm using Ember 1.13

Template...

### Welcome to Ember.js

```
    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
         {{view "select"
            multiple=true 
            class="form-control input-sm" 
            content=pa.options 
            selection=pa.selectedList 
            optionValuePath="content.name" 
            optionLabelPath="content.name" 
            disabled=pa.isDisabled}}
  </script>
```

Javascript...

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function () {
    // put your routes here
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

    pa: function(){
        var optionsList = Ember.A();
        optionsList.pushObjects([
                    Ember.Object.create({name: 'Option 0'}),
                    Ember.Object.create({name: 'Option 1'}),
                    Ember.Object.create({name: 'Option 2'})
        ]);

        var selectedList = Ember.A();
        selectedList.pushObjects([
                    Ember.Object.create({name: 'Option 0'}),
                    Ember.Object.create({name: 'Option 2'})
        ]);

        return Ember.Object.create({
            isDisabled: false,
            options: optionsList,
            selectedList: selectedList
        });
    }.property()
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ember.Select does not do deep checking for objects equality

Meaning `var a = { foo:"bar"}` and `var b {foo:"bar"}` are not equal

here is a fixed fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/u6f0jdw5/

you'll see that both selected and options reference the same objects which now works.

see [#5259](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/5259) and [#4331](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/5259)

Comment: You nailed it. Thanks.  It's also helpful to see your code.  It's never been clear to me when I can use native Javascript types (array, object hash, etc.) versus full Ember Objects.

Comment: I just realized another critical change in your solution.  I couldn't get it to work without this change.  You removed this argument in the 'select' handlebars template:  optionValuePath="content.name"

Comment: Try to always stick to native JavaScript types, only create Ember.Object when you want to us it as route model, or another ember specific functionality, ember can still give you binding and many cool stuff for normal types